# dvblast and gstreamer

Tags: video, video-streaming, gstreamer, dvb

I'm trying to play streaming video from dvblast (dvb-s) to my pandaboard and have issues.
Can someone give me any directions?

this is my output:

```
gst-launch-0.10 -vm udpsrc port=1234 multicast-group=239.255.0.1 caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,payload=(int)96" ! .recv_rtp_sink_0 gstrtpbin latency=800 ! rtpmp2tdepay ! tsdemux ! ffdec_h264 ! xvimagesink 

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ... ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause. 
Got message #9 from element "xvimagesink0" (error): GstMessageError, gerror=(GError)NULL, debug=(string)"xvimagesink.c(1428):\ gst_xvimagesink_get_xv_support\ ():\ /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstXvImageSink:xvimagesink0:\012No\ port\ available"; ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstXvImageSink:xvimagesink0: Could not initialise Xv output Additional debug info: xvimagesink.c(1428): gst_xvimagesink_get_xv_support (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstXvImageSink:xvimagesink0: No port available Setting pipeline to NULL ... Freeing pipeline ...
```

Answer (score 1):

seems like your X-server on the pandaboard isn't setup properly.
on the panda, can you run a simple pipeline like the following?

```
gst-launch videotestsrc ! xvimagesink
```

you might want to try the "autovideosink" instead of the "xvimagesink", which can choose the "best" video output among those installed.

Comment: Hi Umlaeute, thank you for the reply. the above command works. I can see the test screen, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: your initial problem report indicates that you had problems with xvimagesink; you might try to use "autoimagesink"

Comment: Ok perfect, autovideosink gives no error, but i get a blank screen.
Does anybody know the correct pipeline for dvb-s stream from dvblast?